# SDカードの画像ファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: spresense

Spresense購入してNeural Networkを動かしたいと考えている者です。
開発ガイド等を参照してどうしても分からない為、ご質問させて下さい。

Spresense SDKにおいて、SDカード内に予め保存してあるJPGまたはPNG画像ファイルを読込み、DNN Runtimeを使って認識処理が出来ないかと考えております。
画像ファイルの読込みを行うAPI等はありますでしょうか？（自作するしかないでしょうか？）

Answer (score 1):

すでに解決されているかもしれませんが、スケッチ例の中にある **"DNNRT"** の **"number_recognition"** サンプルは、まさにSDカード内の画像を読み込んで認識する処理をしています。

ただ、このサンプルの中で使っている画像フォーマットは **"PBM"** です。SPRESENSEのライブラリの中を調べると **NetPBMライブラリ** がありましたのでPBMは公式サポートしているようです。

ですので、ちょっと不便ですが、**"IrfanView"** などを使って、あらかじめ **PNG を PBM に変換**すれば所望の処理はできると思います。

画像ライブラリをもう少し充実させてほしいですよね。

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、御回答頂きありがとうございました。現状ではOpenCVみたいにJPG画像ファイルを読み込むのは難しそうですね。